# Firebase functions deploy dependency TypeError

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Starting to use mongodb nodejs client in my firebase functions. When deploying Firebase gives me a TypeError on the whatwg-url sub-dependency of the mongo package.

It builds fine and works in an express server with the same code and packages. I can't figure out why it's throwing a type error on code that's already buil.

```
[2023-06-14T20:29:13.266Z] Building nodejs source
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env. 
[2023-06-14T20:29:14.529Z] Could not parse firebase-functions version '' into semver. Falling back to parseTriggers.
```

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.../node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:368181:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:500133:42)
    at Object.../node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:365581:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:500133:42)
    at Object.../node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:368336:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:500133:42)
    at Object.../node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:365252:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:500133:42)
    at Object.../node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js (/home/robbyriley/snarf/functions/lib/index.js:363959:20)`
```

I've tried changing versions on firebase-tools and firebase-functions to "latest" to no avail.

Comment: You should probably edit the question to show enough information and instructions that someone can use to reproduce the error.  An error message alone isn't too helpful - we need to see what you're doing to cause it and be able to do the same ourselves.